# Unable to get PHP with C++ working

Tags: php, c++, class, php-extension

I have an existing C++ library with a class in it that I would like to interface with PHP.  I tried going through the simple example here: http://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension/ and I am running into a syntax error running ./configure.

My code looks like this:

```
[config.m4]
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(sigx,
    [Whether to enable the "SIGX" extension],
    [ --enable-sigx     Enable "SIGX" extension support])

if test "$PHP_SIGX" != "no"; then
    PHP_REQUIRE_CXX();
    PHP_SUBST(SIGX_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(stdc++, 1, SIGX_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(sigx, sigx.cc, $ext_shared)
fi

[sigx.h]
#ifndef PHP_SIGX_H
#define PHP_SIGX_H

#define PHP_SIGX_EXTNAME  "sigx"
#define PHP_SIGX_EXTVER   "0.1"

#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

extern "C" {
#include "php.h"
}

extern zend_module_entry sigx_module_entry;
#define phpext_sigx_ptr &sigx_module_entry;

#endif /* PHP_SIGX_H */

[sigx.cc]
#include "php_sigx.h"

PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(sigx)
{
    return SUCCESS;
}

zend_module_entry sigx_module_entry = {
#if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >= 20010901
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
#endif
    PHP_SIGX_EXTNAME,
    NULL,                       // Functions
    PHP_MINIT(sigx),
    NULL,                       // MSHUTDOWN
    NULL,                       // RINIT
    NULL,                       // RSHUTDOWN
    NULL,                       // MINFO
#if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >= 200010901
    PHP_SIGX_EXTVER,
#endif
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

#ifdef COMPILE_DL_SIGX
    extern "C" {
ZEND_GET_MODULE(sigx)
}
#endif

$ phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626

$ ./configure
...
...
checking for re2c version... 0.13.5 (ok)
checking for gawk... gawk
checking Whether to enable the "SIGX" extension... yes, shared
./configure: line 4785: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
./configure: line 4785: `;'


ac_compiler_gnu=$ac_cv_c_compiler_gnu

    php_cxx_done=yes
  fi
;    <----  This is line 4785

  PHP_VAR_SUBST="$PHP_VAR_SUBST SIGX_SHARED_LIBADD"
```

I have no idea why this is happening and would greatly appreciate any help here.

Comment: Okay, quick update.  Simply removing that line with the semi-colon on it made the error go away.  Now, I'm having different issues, but that issue went away.  Would like to not have it there in the first place!

Comment: omg - I'm an idiot.

I have an extra semi-colon in the macro!

    PHP_REQUIRE_CXX();

Argh....